# CSS after selector is hiding my element after putting overflow-y in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a div with class 'test' and also I am using 'after' selector to put my small red div on top right of the test div. But when I use overflow-y my small red div is going inside. Without using overflow its fine. Here is the code

```css
    .test{
    border: 1px solid #000;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        overflow-y: auto;
        position: relative;
    }
    .test::after{
    border: 1px solid #000;
        width: 10px;
        height: 10px;
        position: absolute;
        top: -4px;
        content: "";
        right: 0;
        z-index: 999;
        background:red;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="test">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the div to scroll will naturally cause overflowing content to be hidden. You'll need to implement the red square outside of the scrolling div, for example wrapping it in another element.